# Timeouts in camel

Tags: jms, apache-camel

I'm using the split-aggregate functionality in Camel to split some work up amongst some JMS clients.
The Camel route is defined (using groovy) as follows:

```
from("vm:getQuotes")
        .split(new MethodCallExpression("requestSplitter", "splitAmongstBots"), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy())
        .to("jms:queue:quoteRequests?requestTimeout=${responseTimeout}s")
        .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
        .end()
```

The JMS clients can take between approx 15 and 90 seconds to process the tasks.
I'm seeing this exception 30secs after the initial split:

```
Caused by: org.apache.camel.ExchangeTimedOutException: The OUT message was not received within: 30000 millis. Exchange[Message: {village=CHEC}]
    at org.apache.camel.component.seda.SedaProducer.process(SedaProducer.java:144)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProducer.process(UnitOfWorkProducer.java:68)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:375)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$2.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:343)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:233)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:343)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:201)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:128)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:115)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBodyAndHeader(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:182)
    ... 116 common frames omitted
```

I have tried adding this line into the route just after the call to `split`:

```
.timeout(1000L * 60)
```

but to no avail - the exception is still thrown after 30 seconds.

Any ideas how I can increase the timeout that is in effect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timeout comes from the vm endpoint, see (vm extends seda)

- http://camel.apache.org/seda

You can set a higher timeout there, or configure it to not wait for task to complete.

Comment: Sorry Claus, can you spell it out for me in more detail?
I tried changing the first line of my route from this:

    from("vm:getQuotes")
to this:

    from("vm:getQuotes?timeout=90000")

But I still get the 30sec timeout.

Where/how exactly do I override the timeout?

Thanks

Comment: Finally getting back to this after a week of hipstering & hustling (when all I wanna do is hacking).
Anyway, the mistake I was making is that even though I had specified the timeout in the route definition like so:  
`"vm:getQuotes?timeout=90000"`
, I was still just using `"vm:getQuotes"` when I pushed the message into the route like so:
`producer.requestBodyAndHeader("vm:getQuotes?timeout=${responseTimeout}", ...)`

Once I changed that call to this, it just worked:
`producer.requestBodyAndHeader("vm:getQuotes?timeout=${responseTimeout}", ...)`

Thanks again Claus.